# Group of line bundles with $\otimes$ isomorphic to $H^1(B,\mathbb{Z}_2)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

I want to prove that all line bundles with the same base $B$ form group with operation $\otimes$ which isomorphic to $H^1(B,\mathbb{Z}_2)$. It's obvious to me, that there is bijection between line bundles and $H^1(B,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ which exists because $B\mathbb{Z}_2 = K(\mathbb{Z}_2,1)$ but I dont understand why that group is isomorphism. I found some proof in [icc prop. 3.7.12](http://www.analg.ulg.ac.be/jps/rec/icc.pdf) but it uses concept of Euler characteristic class, and I want to some prove which uses only concept of Stiefel Whitney class, does that exist? Hope for your help.

Comment: I would recommend [this explanation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531212/line-bundles-of-the-circle) in terms of sheaf cohomology.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Beautiful explanation!