# Showing every vector bundle on $\mathbb{R}$ is trivial not using parallel transport

Tags: differential-topology, vector-bundles

For my differential topology course I need to prove that every vector bundle over $S^1$ is either trivial or equivelent to the Moebius bundle.

I found this nice, elementary proof: [Line bundles of the circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531212/line-bundles-of-the-circle), but it uses that every vector bundle over $\mathbb{R}$ is trivial.
The proofs of this statement I found all use parallel transport, which we haven´t defined in the lecture and which we therefore shouldn´t use.
Does anybody have a proof not using parallel transport or any other sophisticated tool like cohomology theory?

Comment: It's well known that fiber bundles over contractible spaces are trivial. Here's a link for a proof for bundles over Euclidean spaces:  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1085448/55622

Comment: For vector bundles, you may need to add paracompactness.